# How can I remove an item from a list?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new on mvvm:
Normal ways:

```
double progress;
    private DownloadOperation _activeDownload;
    private async void ProgressCallback(DownloadOperation obj)
    {
        try
        {
            progress
            = ((double)obj.Progress.BytesReceived / obj.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive);
            processDownload.Value = progress * 100;
            double _bytesToMBreceived = (double)(obj.Progress.BytesReceived / 1024) / 1024;
            double _bytesToMBtotal = (double)(obj.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024) / 1024;
            buffering.Text = "Downloading..." + string.Format("{0:0.00}", _bytesToMBreceived) + "MB /" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", _bytesToMBtotal) + "MB";
            if (progress >= 1.0)
            {
                _activeDownload = null;
                processDownload.Value = 0;
                buffering.Text = "Completed...";
                await Task.Delay(500);
                gridDownload.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

                var dialog = new MessageDialog("Download has completed");
                await dialog.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }

    }
    private async Task StartDownloadAsync(DownloadOperation downloadoperation)
    {

        gridDownload.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        _activeDownload = downloadoperation;
        buffering.Text = "Waiting for a minute...";
        processDownload.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        var process = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(ProgressCallback);
        await downloadoperation.StartAsync().AsTask(process);
    }
    private async void downloadSongs(string requestUrl, string filename)
    {
        try
        {
            if (filename == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filename");
            //
            var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
            //StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename + ".mp3", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            var regex = new Regex(@"[\\|/\:\*\?""<>\\|]");
            var result_filename = regex.Replace(filename, " ").Replace(";", "");


            FolderPicker fo = new FolderPicker();
            fo.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
            fo.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
            StorageFolder folder = await fo.PickSingleFolderAsync();
            var filePart = await folder.CreateFileAsync(result_filename + ".mp3", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(requestUrl), filePart);
            await StartDownloadAsync(download);
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private async void btnDownload_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (buffering.Text == "Waiting for a minute..." && processDownload.Value == 0 || processDownload.Value != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("You must waiting for downloading completed to download again");
            }
            else
                downloadSongs(_linkdownload, _linktitle);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var Dialog = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
            await Dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

I want to switch this code to mvvm ways(not light mvvm...).
ex:

I have 3 items.

1. item1 downloading 30%->31%->32%(by processbar)
2. item2 waiting 0%
3. item3 waiting 0%

after item1 was finished and removed it then item2 will be downloading....

```
<listbox.....>
   <listbox.Itemtemplate>
      <textblock text={binding title}
      <textblock text{binding status}
      <processbar value={binding process}
........
```

MVVM ways:

```
public class DownloadCommand
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
    public ICommand _downloadCommand { get; set; }

    public DownloadCommand()
    {
        _downloadCommand = new DownloadButtonClick();
    }




    public void ProgressCallBack(DownloadOperation obj)
    {
        double progress = ((double)obj.Progress.BytesReceived / obj.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive);
        double _bytesReceived = (double)(obj.Progress.BytesReceived / 1240);
        double _bytesTotal = (double)(obj.Progress.TotalBytesToReceive / 1240);
        if (progress != 1.0)
        {
            //listbox will removed this item and keep to download at next item.
        }
    }

    private async Task StartDownloadAsync(DownloadOperation obj)
    {
        var process = new Progress<DownloadOperation>(ProgressCallBack);
        await obj.StartAsync().AsTask(process);
    }

    private async void Download(string requestUrl, string filename, string fileType)
    {
        var downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
        var regex = new Regex(@"[\\|/\:\*\?""<>\\|]");
        var result_filename = regex.Replace(filename, " ").Replace(";", "");

        FolderPicker fo = new FolderPicker();
        fo.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
        fo.FileTypeFilter.Add(fileType);
        StorageFolder folder = await fo.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        var filePart = await folder.CreateFileAsync(result_filename + fileType, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri(requestUrl), filePart);
        await StartDownloadAsync(download);
    }

    public class DownloadButtonClick : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**I don't know to write whatever in here.**

```
    public void Execute(object parameter)
            {
                //throw new NotImplementedException();
            }

if (progress != 1.0)
            {
                //listbox will removed this item and keep to download at next item.
            }
```

Comment: 1) What are you trying to do 2) What have you done 3) why is it not working?

Comment: So, listbox have data and then I clicked a item on it and after click button.
I want give three paramerter from source of listbox (var Streamitem = LsvTrackSoundCloud.SelectedItem as Model.TracksSoundCloud.Track;) to 
 private async void Download(string requestUrl, string filename, string fileType)
and I also want to bind name, status, value(value for processbar) to other listbox.

Answer (score 0):

The execute the the entry point to the operation. For example if you have associated the command to a button, this execute will be fired on button click. The parameter is what ever you mention as command parameter in XAML.From there you may call your StartDownloadAsync(). If you have proper data binding progress will reflect in UI. If you have any stripped down working sample, it would be helpful.

Comment: sorry, I'm fist on mvvm so I don't understand what you are talking. Do you write code.

Comment: Do you have a stripped down version of working code which i can look at